# CSS Animation Not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

I have a bit of CSS3 animation which works perfectly in all the browser which support CSS3 except safari. Weird isn't it? Ok here's my code:

What is problem here.

thanks in advance.

CSS:

```
@-o-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

.text-bg2 {
  animation-name:inner-circle; 
  animation-duration:5s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name:inner-circle; 
  -webkit-animation-duration:5s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-name:inner-circle; 
  -o-animation-duration:5s; 
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name:inner-circle; 
  -moz-animation-duration:5s; 
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-name:inner-circle; 
  -ms-animation-duration:5s; 
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="text-bg2"><img src="img/text-bg.png"></div>
```

What am I missing here ? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use just need to add vendor specific css tranfsorm property i.e. wherever (all the places) you have included transform , add two lines of css as follows:

```
@-o-keyframes inner-circle {

    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* added vendor specific css (IE) */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
    }
    5% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);/* added vendor specific css (IE) */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);/* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
    }
    90% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);/* added vendor specific css (IE) */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);/* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);/* added vendor specific css (IE) */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);/* added vendor specific css (Safari, Opera , Chrome) */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@-webkit-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Adding -webkit- in the beginning only, wont change the fact that `transform` needs it aswel. You need to like do it inside the brackets aswel. 
For example:

```
  @-webkit-keyframes inner-circle {
      0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
      5% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
      90% {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
      100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
    }
```

and do that to all the others aswel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the animation name and timing before the keyframes animation and not after

So:

```
.text-bg2 {
  animation-name:inner-circle; 
  animation-duration:5s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name:inner-circle; 
  -webkit-animation-duration:5s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-name:inner-circle; 
  -o-animation-duration:5s; 
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name:inner-circle; 
  -moz-animation-duration:5s; 
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-name:inner-circle; 
  -ms-animation-duration:5s; 
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-o-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes inner-circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  5% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  90% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```